# Magento 2 : How to check MEQP2 for My Extension

Tags: magento2, localhost, xampp, meqp2

I've been trying to validate my extension before submit it to **Magento Marketplace**.

I've installed **MEQP** using composer.

> $ composer create-project --repository=https://repo.magento.com magento/marketplace-eqp magento-coding-standard

But when I am trying to execute below commands as per Magento says it gives me error in my console.

Note: Currently I am on localhost with Xampp on windows OS.

> 1).  Navigated to `magento-coding-standard` directory to my Magento2 root.
>
> 2). C:\xampp\htdocs\m2fresh\magento-coding-standard>cd vendor/bin/phpcs C:\xampp\htd
>   ocs\m2fresh\app\code\Vendor\Module\ --standard=MEQP2

It giving me error like below.

**The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect**

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it creates an Issue because you are passing `cd`(change directory) in your command. try to execute without it. And one more thing If you are using Window OS then you need to make sure about `slash` (forward / or backward ).

Try with below command,

`C:\xampp\htdocs\m2fresh\magento-coding-standard\vendor\bin\phpcs C:\xampp\htdocs\m2fresh\app\code\Vendor\Module\ --standard=MEQP2`

Comment: I did try than now error changes to vendor isn't recognized as an internal or external command. :( No Luck,  Same Issue.

Comment: See my edit and make sure about `slash` @LazyCoder

Comment: One more thing is there any log generated expect console, I can't check all warnings in it ?

Comment: I am not sure about but If you want to submit this extension to marketplace then you need to pass one argument `--severity=10` and IF you are getting any error then you need to resolve this error. And If you want to solve error automatic then you need to pass `phpcbf` instead of `phpcs`

Answer (score 2):

@LazyCoder Yes, You can generate log in an external file.

For that, you need to pass one argument **(> Filename.log)** with the command.

Example:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\m2fresh\magento-coding-standard\vendor\bin\phpcs
C:\xampp\htdocs\m2fresh\app\code\Vendor\Module\ --standard=MEQP2 > test.log
```

The file is created in the path where you apply the command.

Comment: If this answer is really helpful to you then please accept the answer.So it will be helpful for others.

Comment: Both answers helpful can't divide accept answer into 2 parts :)

Comment: It is require to change path any other file inside "Magento_Root/Vendor/bin" ?